# is 2d list supported in python?

Tags: python, list

I encounter a problem when I try to use a list as a 2d array.

```
li = [[0]*3]*3
print li
li[0][0] = 1
print li
```

then the weird thing happens
the output would be:

```
[[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]
[[1,0,0],[1,0,0],[1,0,0]]
```

why it's not

```
[[1,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]
```